# how to create a custom confirmation box in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I was trying to create a confirmation box in my grid view for changing the user status....
I used the default method which was used to create confirmation box for delete
but its not working...

can anyone suggest any other way..

[image: image of my view]

```
'suspend'=>function($url,$model){if($model->user_is_social_worker =='1')
return Html::a('<span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger icon-remove bigger-120"style="margin-left:5px;"></span>',                                                                         $url,['title'=>Yii::t('app','Revoke social worker'),
'data-confirm'=>'are u sure'
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help you:

[paynedigital.com/articles/2011/11/bootbox-js-alert-confirm-dialogs-for-twitter-bootstrap](http://paynedigital.com/articles/2011/11/bootbox-js-alert-confirm-dialogs-for-twitter-bootstrap)

Also check this:

[www.yiiframework.com/wiki/654/escape-from-default-s-yii2-delete-confirm-box/](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/654/escape-from-default-s-yii2-delete-confirm-box/)

Comment: being new to Yii2 i was unable to initialize this can any one please guid me to initiailze this...